# Invoke function from DLL (c#) in Oracle Forms

Tags: c#, forms, oracle, dll

I've got big problem with invoking method from DLL in Oracle Forms 6i. DLL has been written in

C#, and it is code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OnlineFPCommon;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestNamespace 
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static void testMethod()
        {
             MessageBox.Show("testMethod");
        }
    }
}
```

I try to invoke it using Oracle Forms code:

```
testlib_lhandle := Ora_Ffi.Load_library('C:\libdir\','test.dll');
getresult_fhandle := ora_ffi.register_function(testlib_lhandle,'testMethod');
```

but the second line, when I try to register function fails. Why? How Can I properly invoke that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

register_function requires a dll entry point and you cannot generate that in managed code.

You can write a C++/CLi wrapper DLL to have native entry points for your managed code but if you are just starting from scratch then why not just write a plain native dll.

Comment: OK, I change the way of invoking c# dll.
I do it using c++ DLL.

To sum up:
1.) From Oracle Forms I invoke function from DLL written in C++.
2.) Function from C++ DLL invokes function from c# DLL.
3.) And now my oracle forms application crashes.


Hmmm, it is very strange, because I tried the same using c++ application instead Oracle Forms and it works. So what can be an issue, that it doesn't work in Oracle Forms 6?

Comment: try debug the dll with your oracle process as the debug target.