# Where can I find instructions on how to create an Oracle package from a .NET 4.5 DLL?

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, plsql

I have a vendor supplied C# .NET v4.5 DLL. He has supplied an API with documentation. I have written a wrapper in VS2012 Express VB.NET It seems to work when called by other .NET code.

I would like to be able to call my wrapper from PL/SQL. I have done this before with a c++ DLL by creating a library in the DB and adding a package with methods similar to;

```
FUNCTION MyFunc (var1  in varchar2, var2 in varchar2, var3 in varchar2)RETURN PLS_INTEGER
IS
  EXTERNAL 
  LIBRARY MyLibrary 
  NAME "MyFunc"  
  LANGUAGE C 
  PARAMETERS (var1 string, var2 string, var3 string);
```

I would try the above for the .NET code, but I expect it wouldn't work. If it were to work, what is the "LANGUAGE?"

So has anyone done this,? If so can you point me to docs on how easiest to do this.

If at all possible, I would prefer not having to install Oracle tools in .NET, which is always suspect when using the express version of .NET. I would also prefer not having to create a different version of my wrapper for Oracle, as I hate to maintain two sets of code that do the same thing.

Comment: You have two choices when it comes to `LANGUAGE`: `C` or `JAVA`. Neither will do for calling a .NET assembly. In theory, you could use C++/CLI to wrap the .NET code so it can be called directly as `C`.

Comment: Similar Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182806/invoke-function-from-dll-c-in-oracle-forms