# call a C# DLL from oracle forms 6i

Tags: c#, oracle, oracleforms

I need to call a C# DLL from my forms that has the method testMethod()

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void testMethod()
    {
         return "hello world";
    }
}
```

How can I read the return value "hello world"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke function from DLL (c#) in Oracle Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182806/invoke-function-from-dll-c-in-oracle-forms)

Comment: I haven't done this for decades, but search for ORA_FFI.

Comment: I wondering if that still will work.  Wasn't Forms 6i developed for Windows XP?

Comment: After trying my level best, I believe, C# DLL can not be called in Oracle forms directly.